# Conversion Failed in a CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column that is of `varchar` type, it contains dates and '#':

```
31.01.2022
31.01.2022
30.11.2021
31.12.2021
30.11.2021
28.02.2022
28.02.2022
#
```

I am trying to convert the dates to the standard date format (YYYY-MM-DD) and leave the '#' as it is whenever it occurs.

Here is my code:

```
CASE 
    WHEN table.CalendarColumn='#' THEN '#'
    ELSE CONVERT(date, table.CalendarColumn, 104) END AS Calendar
```

The outcome column is also of `varchar(10)` type (same as the original column).

I expected to get # whenever the cell is # and the converted Date whenever it is not # but I get this error instead:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

Comment: I think you've a mix of '#' and dates.

Comment: `CASE` isn't a function, it's an expression, and it returns a **scalar** value. If the values you try to return are of different data types, then [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is used to determine the resulting data type. You have a `date` and a `varchar(1)`, and `date` has a higher precedence, so SQL Server attempts to convert the `varchar(1)`. Unsurprisingly, `'#'` is *not* a valid `date` value, and hence the error. What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: `WHEN table.CalendarColumn='#'` This suggests that your column `CalendarColumn` isn't a date and time data type to start with; this is a design flaw which you need to fix.

Comment: `CONVERT(date, table.CalendarColumn, 104)` doesn't convert to a `varchar(10)`, it converts to a `date`; the **first** parameter of `CONVERT` defines the target data type.

Comment: Don't store your dates in a varchar columns, use a proper date data type instead.

Comment: @Larnu Seems quite clear the intention here: to transform the `varchar` value into the correct date style *where it is a valid date* and leave it otherwise. So it needs to stay as a `varchar`, that is what they want to achieve. Why you would want to do that, and not store as an actual date column, is an entirely different question.

Comment: I'd argue that there's a reason why they want to convert it back to a `varchar` and we don't know that reason, @Charlieface . At a guess, they want to format the date in their presentation layer and it's not working; due to it not being a `date` but a `varchar`.

Comment: Appreciate your input everyone! 
@Larnu thank you for the Data Type Precedence documentation . 
The 'CalenderColumn' is varchar format as some of its records are '#' and that's beyond my control, I will need to leave it as it is and can't ignore the entire row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of data type precedence, the compiler is trying to convert `#` to a date.

So you need to convert the `date` value back to a `varchar` instead, in the style you want. A shorter syntax is to use `TRY_CONVERT` and `ISNULL`

```sql
SELECT
  ISNULL(
    CONVERT(varchar(20),
      TRY_CONVERT(date, table.CalendarColumn, 104),
      23),
    table.CalendarColumn) AS Calendar
FROM....
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1fc4f83de1bd02e1c308932a225f4c2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Charlieface! 
Because the column is Varchar, I expected the date output to be varchar as well but it wasn't hence another convert was necessary.

I got to know about data type precedence in CASE expressions, thanks to @Larnu.